# php.ini configuration

Tags: php-5.3

can any one explain inter relation between these below given directives

```
; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
; line unless ignore_repeated_source is set true.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-errors
ignore_repeated_errors = off

; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting
; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
; source lines.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-source
ignore_repeated_source = off
```

Comment: It's to try and cut down on the size of logs by only logging one error of that type if they are duplicates. ignore_repeated_erorrs is useful since it only is concerned what that one file, but be aware if you get the errors on multiple lines then it might be good to turn it off. Duplicate removing can be useful sometimes but I prefer to see every file that makes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-repeated-errors):

> ignore_repeated_errors
> Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in the same file on the same line unless ignore_repeated_source is set true.
>
> ignore_repeated_source
> Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or sourcelines.

`ignore_repeated_errors` set `On` will suppress multiple occurrences of the same errors when they come from the same line of the same file.

Setting `ignore_repeated_source` to `On` **as well** will suppress multiple occurrences of the same errors, even if they come from different lines in different files.

Answer (score 1):

A repeated message is one created on the same line in the same file. This could be in a loop or in a function:

```
for (...) {
  someFunctionThatFails();
}
```

By enabling the second option, a repeated message does not need to be on the same line or file. A message of a certain type will then just be logged once per request. This will then give only one logged message:

```
someFunctionThatFails();
doSomeThingElse();
someFunctionThatFails();
```